# The VNet created doesnot show up in the route table configuration in Azure

Tags: azure

I am trying to set up a Vnet for the infra for our SharePoint project.
Using Azure Portal , I created the below in the same Resource Group:
Vnet and its two subnets
Two NSG - Associated it to the respective Subnets ( One for front end and one for backend )
Two VM( Linux)
Route table.

When I select the Subnets in Route table and click Associate, it doesnt give me the Vnet that I have created in the dropdown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dGeT.png)

How to fix this?

Comment: May you please check if you created Route table and Vnet in same Azure Regions?

Comment: Yes Route table was in a different region. I am just a beginner in Azure. took three hours to figure it out.  Thank you so much !! :)

Comment: How do I mark this as an answer?

Comment: Answer is added, however you can raise comment as useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you created Route table and Vnet in same Azure Regions